# Correlation across a Markov chain

Tags: statistics, markov-chains

If I have three Normal Distributions that form a Markov Chain
X->Y->Z

such that the correlation between X and Y is $\rho_{x,y}$ and between Y and Z is $\rho_{y,z}$.

I believe the correlation between X and Z should be $\rho_{x,y}\rho_{y,z}$, but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you assume that $P_{X,Y,Z}$ is multivariate normal (i.e., they are jointly Gaussian), then this indeed is true. You can do this by direct integration $p(x, z) = \int p(x\mid y) p(z\mid y) p(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$.

Answer (score 0):

We will assume that the joint distribution $p(x, y, z)$ is multivariate normal.

As translations and (non-zero) scaling of each variable does not change the correlation, we can assume that each $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ is a Gaussian variable with zero mean and unit variance.

In this case, we have
$$\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho_{XY} \\ \rho_{XY} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$p(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-\rho_{XY}^2}} \exp \left(-\frac{x^2 - 2\rho_{XY}xy +y^2}{2(1-\rho_{XY}^2)}\right).$$

Using the Markov chain structure we note that

\begin{align*}
  p(x, y, z) &= p(x\mid y) p(z\mid y) p(y)\\
  &= \frac{p(x, y) p(y, z)}{p(y)}\\
  &= \frac{\exp \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{x^2-2 \rho_{XY} x y+y^2}{1-\rho_{XY}^2}-\frac{y^2-2
   \rho_{YZ} y z+z^2}{1-\rho_{YZ}^2}+y^2\right)  }{(2\pi)^{3/2} \sqrt{(1-\rho_{XY}^2)(1-\rho_{YZ}^2)}} \end{align*}

Now we need to integrate:
$$p(x, z) = \int p(x, y, z) \, \mathrm{d}y.$$

Note that
$$\int e^{-ay^2 + bx + c} \, \mathrm{d}y \propto e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}+c},$$
so that after rearranging the above expression into this quadratic form:

$$y^2
   \left(-\frac{1}{2 \left(1-\rho _{XY}^2\right)}-\frac{1}{2 \left(1-\rho
   _{YZ}^2\right)}+\frac{1}{2}\right) y \left(\frac{x \rho_{XY}}{1-\rho
   _{XY}^2}+\frac{z \rho _{YZ}}{1-\rho _{YZ}^2}\right)  -\frac{z^2}{2 \left(1-\rho _{YZ}^2\right)} -\frac{x^2}{2 \left(1-\rho _{XY}^2\right)}$$

one can read out that the correlation is indeed $\rho_{XY}\rho_{YZ}$.